# CSS: Change position of div on hover

Tags: html, css

In the Following HTML, the initial position of `.layer` is set at `top: -100%`, I want to change it on hover over the `.image` div. I am trying following code but it does not seem do anything on hover.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8356/8332233161_18e3a75de0_m.jpg" ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="layer">Hide it first, show on hover over image</div>
     <div class="other">other</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 240px;
}

.box .image{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

.box .layer{
    width: 240px;
    height: 146px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
}

.box .image:hover .layer{
    top: 0  
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/pY9jx/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was the selector you were using, a space between elements implies the second element is a descendant of the former, whereas in this case the elements are adjacent siblings, a relationship described using the `+` combinator; therefore:

```
.image:hover + .layer,
.layer:hover {
    top: 0  
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pY9jx/1/).

The reason that I've also defined the rule to apply to the `.layer:hover` is to avoid [the flickering](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pY9jx/2/) that otherwise results when the `.layer` is placed under the cursor, which stops the `.layer:hover` selector applying (as the `.layer` is, effectively, 'in the way').

References:

- [Adjacent-sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).
- [CSS Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I just added margin in your example, and it does not work properly. Even the .image position is relative, the .layer does not seem to care about that: http://jsfiddle.net/pY9jx/12/

Answer (score 1):

The style rule of the hover state applies to `.box .image:hover .layer`. This means it would be applied to an element of class `layer` that is nested within an element of class `image`. However, in your current code the `layer` element is not nested inside the `image` element.

To solve this, simply move the `layer` element into the `image` element, like so:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="image">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8356/8332233161_18e3a75de0_m.jpg" ></a>
    <div class="layer">Hide it first, show on hover over image</div>
</div>
<div class="other">other</div>
```

Test it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/pY9jx/3/